# Can I search bash history across all users on a server?

Tags: linux, bash, users, command-history

I want to see all bash commands that have been run on a Linux server across multiple user accounts. The specific distribution I'm using is CentOS 5.7. Is there a way to globally search .bash_history files on a server or would it be a more home-grown process of `locate | cat | grep`? (I shudder just typing that out).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `getent` to enumerate the home directories.

```
getent passwd |
cut -d : -f 6 |
sed 's:$:/.bash_history:' |
xargs -d '\n' grep -s -H -e "$pattern"
```

If your home directories are in a well-known location, it could be as simple as

```
grep -e "$pattern" /home/*/.bash_history
```

Of course, if a user uses a different shell or a different value of `HISTFILE`, this won't tell you much. Nor will this tell you about commands that weren't executed through a shell, or about aliases and functions and now-removed external commands that were in some user directory early in the user's `$PATH`. If what you want to know is what commands users have run, you need process accounting or some fancier auditing system; see [Monitoring activity on my computer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4275/monitoring-activity-on-my-computer), [How to check how long a process ran after it finished?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13445/how-to-check-how-long-a-process-ran-after-it-finished).

Comment: +1 for suggesting process accounting instead.  History files are really for user convenience and there are no simple ways to make them fool-proof enough for any sort of logging purposes.

Comment: @jw013 Yes, I've already had my fill of how easy it is to edit / modify and otherwise muck with shell history. =|

Comment: This is an old question, but it was my first google result, so maybe worth adding to. I modified this to check that the file exists before trying to grep it:
`getent passwd | cut -d : -f 6 | sed "s:$:/.bash_history:" | xargs -d'\n' -I{} sh -c "[ -f {} ] && echo {}" | xargs -d'\n' grep -Hn -e "$pattern"`

Comment: @BryKKan Ignoring non-existent files is a good idea. Beware that the way you're doing it is dodgy: it should work in practice given that typical user names don't contain “weird” characters, but in general using `{}` like this is very dangerous. The file name is interpolated directly in the script. If you have a file name (here: a user name) containing, say, `$(rm -rf /)` or `;rm -rf /;`, the command will be executed. Always pass file names as arguments to shell scripts, never use find or xargs's `{}` mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

```
find /home -name .bash_history | xargs grep <string>
```

Alternatively:

```
grep string $(find /home -name .bash_history)
```

Note that this covers home directories in default locations. It would be better to parse `/etc/passwd` or invoke `getent`, and parse the output of that.

```
for i in $(getent passwd | cut -d: -f6 ); do grep string ${i}/.bash_history; done
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
find /home | grep bash_history | xargs grep "whatever"
```

But I don't really think that is much better then what you were thinking.