# How to get the command line history of another user?

Tags: bash, rhel, sudo, command-history, su

I currently have a server set up to save Bash history for every user immediately in their respective home folders and I want to create a script that runs on a set interval that switches the current user and executes the "history" command.

I have tried all variants of both su and sudo in the command line but whenever I run the command "history" for another user in a script or usind su/do, I get no output whatsoever.

In scripts, I have tried all variants of both su and sudo, as well as:

```
su <user>
history
```

But all it does is open a shell with that user and doesn't return the output of "history".

I'm currently using RHEL6.9 with Bash 4.1.2.

EDIT:

I have a log collector that currently monitors all .bash_history files, but I configured /etc/bashrc to append timestamp and user so I can assign fields and log the exact time execution of each command. Because the internal format that Bash stores command line history in .bash_history is to just add the epoch time, I need to be able to execute "history" on each individual user.

I have tried (separately) the following from the command line, as well as in scripts:

```
su -c "history" <user>
sudo -i -u <user> history
sudo -S -u <user> -i /bin/bash -l -c 'history'
```

I have tried to do this in scripts:

```
su -i <user>
history
```

But they never return any results.

Comment: Possibly related: [Can I search bash history across all users on a server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31723/can-i-search-bash-history-across-all-users-on-a-server/31731)

Comment: Try using `su - <user>` instead of `su <user>`. Check out this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7017/258298)

Comment: @Paulo Tomé So I want to be able to run "history" on a script since I have formatted in /etc/bashrc how each entry is recorded (timestamp, etc.), which is why that answer does not work for me since it reads .bash_history, which I have already tested, only adds timestamp data, and is on epoch on top of that

Comment: @Amit Singh That is one of the variations I have tried, which is why I don't understand why I am getting no output. I have tried redirecting both stout and sterr to a file, but there's never any data generated

Comment: @AnthonyBB It's not clear what is your goal. Can you share what have you already tried?

Comment: @AnthonyBB Please edit the question to provide exactly what you want to achieve and what you have already done.

Comment: Taking a guess at what the OP is trying to achieve, recording all commands of users and saving it in a file with timestamp. Am I right?

Comment: @Jetchisel That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script and save it somewhere in PATH that is available for all users. e.g. `/bin` or `/usr/bin`

The script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history
history -r
unset HISTFILE
history
```

Save it to a name like `print_history`

Now try

```
su - user_name -c 'print_history'
```

You said you have the time format in `/etc/bashrc` so I did not unset the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` in that script. The idea for that script is not mine, I personally use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable to capture every commands (and every user in my system) that is typing/running commands during interactive session so I don't use that script so that's all I can say about that script. Of course all the user must be using bash as the log-in shell.